# Разные папки видов в Node js

Tags: node.js, express, jade

Добрый вечер друзья, у меня возник вопрос. Делаю сайт на Node.js (это мое первое приложение на Node) использую framework express и шаблонизатор jade. В приложении имеется 2 модуля, сам сайт и админ панель к нему. Создал два rout'a возникла проблема с видами: не хочу все держать в одной папке `views`, хочу отдельно создать `views/admin`, но не получается. Делаю так:

```
exports.home = function (req, res) {
    res.render('/admin/index', {
        title: "ProgBook.Uz",
        "message": "Admin Panel"
    });
};
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать и как?
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Выводится ли какая-нибудь ошибка в консоли или на странице?

Comment: @Michael Radionov Ошибку исправил дело было не в видах, а в маршрутизации. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @ElSalvadore, вы можете оставить ответ на свой собственный вопрос. Возможно, это поможет тем, кто столкнется с аналогичной проблемой

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev я просто не указал маршрут для данной функции:     routes.get('/admin/');

Comment: @ElSalvadore, то есть ошибка вообще не в приведенном коде?

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev, да ошибка в другом коде.

Answer (score -1):

Уберите слэш

```
res.render('admin/index', {
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?